# Does the spin1/2 rotation operator rotate spin in real space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, coordinate-systems, rotation

in quantum mechanics, the rotation operator for spin one half is $R_{\alpha}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\right)=\mbox{exp}\left(-i\frac{\alpha}{2}\boldsymbol{\sigma}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\right)$. And a rotation of 360 degree will give a minus to the wave function.

My question is that does this operator describe the spin rotation in real space?
For example, if a solid has a local rotation caused by phonons or defect, can I use this operator to describe the effect on the spin degree?